# Does Ruby on rails refreshes pages by default or uses ajax?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I would like to know this since I have to make a site.....When I go to another action or module, will it refresh the webpage of it automatically uses ajax avoiding page refresh?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, Rails does not use AJAX, and you'll need to refresh the current page to reflect any server-side changes.

With that said, Rails does make it very, very easy to work with AJAX. I'd suggest you check this out: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html

Answer (score 4):

Rails uses Turbolinks by default, so yes it uses Ajax. However this can mess with your Javascript callbacks if they aren't handled properly.

If you want to remove this feature just delete the `data-turbolinks` attribute in your scripts

Comment: or simply uninstall turbolinks by removing it from the Gemfile.

Comment: yeyo, simply uninstalling turbolinks from Gemfile won't do it completely. You have to remove it from Gemfile, rerun bundle, then also remove the remnants of it in the application layout and application.js

Comment: Yes, to remove it completely you have to remove it from Gemfile, remove the references from the layout, and run bundler

Comment: Or add the jquery-turbolinks gem and have all the callbacks work fine

Answer (score 1):

Rails is built on [HTTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) which means that any correspondence with the server *has* to result in a response (even if the response is a [`200`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#2xx_Success)).

If you are not using ajax, nor have defined `layout: false`, Rails will automatically send a fully-rendered set of HTML back to the browser with each response. This will include `<head>` etc.

--

[`Turbolinks`](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks) is designed to speed this up by pulling *only* the `<body>` tag of your page through ajax:

> Instead of letting the browser recompile the JavaScript and CSS between each page change, it keeps the current page instance alive and replaces only the body (or parts of) and the title in the head.

So to answer your question; "default" Rails will cause a full browser refresh; using `Turbolinks` will speed it up by only pulling the `<body>` tag from the server response via ajax.